# How do I find this sum: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arccos\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This originates from Pythagoras spiral, where this practically considers the angle of which the spiral turns.

I genuinely don't know how to approach this.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arccos\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}.$$

EDIT: Sorry this is my first post, this is what I know. I know that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}=1$$

and

$$\arccos(1)=0$$

so hence I would assume that by considering the Pythagorean spiral, where you construct a right triangle with adjacent side length $1$ and opposite side length, thereby making the hypothenuse equal $\sqrt 2$, and constructing a new triangle by having that be the adjacent side, keeping the opposite side at length $1$, thereby making the new hypothesis have length $\sqrt 3$, and continuing this process, the angle between the hypothenuse and adjacent side decreases. I wonder, could you know the total amount of rotation that this process creates, this is what the formula above refers to. I don't know how to proceed with evaluating it.

Hopefully this made it clear.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $\sqrt{(n+1)/n}>1$

Comment: This was asked a few days ago but got removed

Comment: The series is divergent, since it is asymptotically equivalent to $$\sum 1/\sqrt n$$ That's because $$\arccos \sqrt{(n-1)/n} = \arcsin 1/ \sqrt n \approx 1/ \sqrt n$$

Comment: This series diverges. The spiral will eventually loop all the way round over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

All having been said in comments, you could have considered the easy continuous case
$$I_p=\int_0^p  \cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)\,dn$$

$$I_p=\sqrt{p}+p \cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{p}{p+1}}\right)-\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{p}\right)-1$$ and for large $p$
$$I_p=2 \sqrt{p}-\left(1+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{p}}\left(1-\frac{1}{5 p}+\frac{3}{35
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Combining your computations with the Euler–Maclaurin formula yields $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\arccos \left( {\sqrt {\frac{n}{{n + 1}}} } \right)}  = 2\sqrt N  + C + \frac{7}{{6\sqrt N }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{N^{3/2} }}} \right)
$$ where $$C = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\binom{2k}{k}\frac{{\zeta (k + 1/2) - 1}}{{(2k + 1)4^k }}}  =  - 2.15778299665944758 \ldots\,.
$$

Comment: @Gary. Thanks for pointing and thanks for this interesting $C$